# import json as variable in shell script on windows and linux?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to read data from a json file into my azure devops as variable.

I saw this post:
[import Azure Devops pipeline variables from json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58597755/import-azure-devops-pipeline-variables-from-json-file)

But the answer here is only powershell compatible.

Is ther any solution that works with linux and windows agents?

Comment: I introduced the variable store method in the pipeline run life cycle and the permanent variable store method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, powershell should not only works on windows but also works on linux.

[Install PowerShell on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux?view=powershell-7.3)

Second, for your requirement, I write a demo YAML for you(based on python):

## 1, Get the value of the specific route of json, and set it as variables in pipeline concept.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      import json
      
      def get_json_content_of_specific_route(json_file_path, json_route):
          length = len(json_route)
          # print(length)
          
          #open json file
          with open(json_file_path, 'r') as f:
              data = json.load(f)
              content = data
              #get the content f data[json_route[0]][json_route[1]]...[json_route[length-1]]
              for i in range(length):
                  if i == 0:
                      content = data[json_route[i]]
                  else:
                      content = content[json_route[i]]
              
              #get the content
              return content
      
      json_file_path = 'Json_Files/parameters.json' #This is the path of the json file.
      route = ['parameters', 'secretsPermissions', 'value'] #This is the route of the content you want to get.
      
      content = get_json_content_of_specific_route(json_file_path, route)
      
      print(content)
      print("##vso[task.setvariable variable=myJobVar]"+str(content))
  
- powershell: |
    Write-Host $(myJobVar) #you can get the content after you using logging command to set the variables.
```

The above variables getting from json can be Temporary set and use in pipeline run.

See [using logging command to set the variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#levels-of-output-variables).

This is the structure of my repository:

[image]

Set and get the variable successfully in pipeline run lifecycle:

[image]

## 2, If you want permanent variables, there are two situations.

***1' When based on classic pipeline, you need to use these REST API to achieve your requirements:***

[Get pipeline definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)

[Change pipeline definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)

A python script that can change the variables of the classic pipeline:

```
import json
import requests


org_name = "xxx"
project_name = "xxx"
pipeline_definition_id = "xxx"
personal_access_token = "xxx"

key = 'variables'
var_name = 'BUILDNUMBER'

url = "https://dev.azure.com/"+org_name+"/"+project_name+"/_apis/build/definitions/"+pipeline_definition_id+"?api-version=6.0"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic '+personal_access_token
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
json_content = response.text
def get_content_of_json(json_content, key, var_name):
    data = json.loads(json_content)
    return data[key][var_name].get('value')

def change_content_of_json(json_content, key, var_name):
    data = json.loads(json_content)
    data[key][var_name]['value'] = str(int(get_content_of_json(json_content,key,var_name)) + 1)
    return data

json_data = change_content_of_json(json_content, key, var_name)


url2 = "https://dev.azure.com/"+org_name+"/"+project_name+"/_apis/build/definitions/"+pipeline_definition_id+"?api-version=6.0"

payload2 = json.dumps(json_data)
headers2 = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic '+personal_access_token,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response2 = requests.request("PUT", url2, headers=headers2, data=payload2)
```

***2' If your pipeline is based on non-classic pipeline, then you need to change the variables part of YAML file definition.***

After you change the YAML definition during pipeline run, you can follow this to push back the changes:

[Push Back Changes to Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74367845/trigger-python-script-through-changes-on-azure/74369455#74369455)

Also, you can make your pipeline based on variables group and update the variables group via REST API:

[Variablegroups - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)